# Is motor transportation in Jakarta dangerous?

Tags: safety, traffic, jakarta

While being in Jakarta will be dealing with motorized vehicles, whether your are walking, in a car, or in a motorcycle. If you take the taxi for instance, you will notice cars don’t have a safety belt in the back. If you take an ojek (moto-taxi), the driver will give you a shitty helmet and drive recklessly, putting your life in danger every second.

Comment: Are you answering your question in the post? I'm unclear as to what you're after? How does one measure danger? You take a risk every time you leave your house ever day...

Comment: Travel a bit more and you'll find that people wearing safety belts are the exception, not the rule (as was the case in the West until maybe 30 years ago). Same goes for motorbike helmets.

Comment: Isn't motor transportation dangerous everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

No, not safe if you are comparing that to western standards. I live in Jakarta half of the year for many years now and I never tried ojek because I do not think it is safe, but that's due to personal issues with motorcycles.

Anyway, inside cities motorcycles will not have a chance to go really fast, and in my years here I have never seen a serious ojek accident inside cities to be honest. So you can use ojek as long as it is inside cities and condensed areas as it is the fastest transportation method.

Comment: You've been pretty lucky then: 120 people a *day* die on Indonesia's roads, the majority of them on two or three wheels.  http://pulitzercenter.org/reporting/asia-indonesia-jakarta-road-fatal-driving-economy-public-infrastructure-bus-motorcycle-accident